# log4net not logging in ASP.Net anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, log4net

We have two ASP.Net Web-forms applications. One is a sub-application of the other in IIS. Both applications use log4net for logging and both applications keep their log4net configuration in their web.config files.

Since the last deploy the child applications are not logging anymore. Does anyone have experience with such issues?

**Details**

The strange part is that it worked before. I have tried wrapping the parent configuration part into

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

parts with no effect. I noticed though that when the parent application was stopped the logging resumed correctly. Putting the parent application offline the second time did not start logging. Is there some kind of configuration caching when inheriting configuration from parent applications?

Configuration part in web.config:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <!-- ... Other content -->
    <log4net>
        <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
                <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="AppRollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value=".\Logs\Application.log" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="[%-5level][%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff}][%file:%L] %m%n" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
            <appender-ref ref="AppRollingFile" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? imho, if the apps are launched separately, then you might get a conflict if both try to use the same file. Try to get them logging to different files.

Comment: This is what I am trying to find out by using absolute paths. I will come back with the results. Another thing I will try is separating the log4net config from the rest. TY